# Prediction by Neural network Keras is not working

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network

I want to write a NN program for recognition using Keras.

I have used 2 sets of data for training:

```
toyX = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
toyX2 = [18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11].
```

After  training with `toyX` and then `toyX2`, the output of `model.predict(toyX)` is `[[0.56053144 1.0758346  1.7890009 ]]`. However, it should have been `[6, 11, 14]`.

Should I add more layers or change parameters to improve prediction? Which parameters I should change?

Please help me to solve this problem.

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.layers import Conv1D, MaxPooling1D
from keras.layers import Dense, Flatten
from keras.layers import Dropout
import numpy as np

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', input_shape=(8, 1)))
model.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
#model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))
model.add(Dense(3))
#model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
print(model.summary())


toyX = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]).reshape(1, 8, 1)
toyX2 = np.array([18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11]).reshape(1, 8, 1)
#print (toyX.shape)
toyY = np.array([6, 11, 14]).reshape(1, 3)
#print (toyY.shape)
toyY2 = np.array([1, 2, 3]).reshape(1, 3) # if flatten is active

model.fit(toyX, toyY, epochs = 1000, verbose = 0)
model.fit(toyX2, toyY2, epochs = 1000, verbose = 0)

print (model.predict(toyX))
```

Comment: Why are you expecting to predict [6, 11, 14] ? After train your model with `toyX` and `toyY`, you train your same model with different dataset which means your weights of neural network changed. Even if you don't train with the second data set, it may not give directly [6, 11, 14] but probably the similar.

Comment: I expecting a prediction value as near as possible to [6, 11, 14]. However, the prediction result is way off.  There is nothing special about [6, 11, 14]. It is just an example. My point is NN prediction is broken down once it is trained with another value.

Comment: You train your NN with very different two distributions. Increasing the complexity of your neural network may help with this issue because you will increase the entropic capacity of your model. However, as @zabir mentioned "You should train only for very few epochs with a really small learning rate if you want to make sure the knowledge of previous training stays or just mix both of the sets and re-train."

Answer (score 1):

This phenomenon is called catastrophic forgetting of neural networks.

You can read a paper on this: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1708.02072.pdf

Your `toyX` and `toyX2` has a completely different distribution. When you re-train your model with ToyX2 for 1000 epochs, your model has completely forgotten the mapping from `toyX` to `toyY`.

You should train only for very few epochs with a really small learning rate if you want to make sure the knowledge of previous training stays or just mix both of the sets and re-train.